# Proving $f(x)=x\cdot |x|$ is a bijection

Tags: proof-verification

Prove that the function $f: R\to R$ given $f(x)=x\cdot |x|$ is a bijection

Proof 1: f is injective

Suppose $$f(a) = f(b) \implies a\cdot |a| = b\cdot |b|$$
$$\implies (a\cdot |a|)^2 = (b\cdot |b|)^2$$
$$\implies a^4 =b^4$$
$$a=b$$ Thus, f is injective

Proof 2: f is surjective

Pick $n\in R$, we want to show $n=f(x)$ for some $x\in R$

$$\implies n= a\cdot |a|$$ for some $a\in R$

I dont know how to complete the surjective proof

Comment: $a^4=b^4$ does not imply that $a=b$.

Comment: @lulu but since they have same exponent, i thought a=b

Comment: No.  $(-1)^4=1^4$, for example.  You need to modify your argument to take signs into account (i.e. first assume $a,b>0$ then $a>0,b<0$ and so on.)

Comment: "but since they have same exponent, i thought a=b"  Why?  Does $x^4 = k$ have only one solution?  What if $a$ is one of the solutions and b is the other.  in general squaring both sides of an equation *ADD* extra false solutions.

Comment: @fleablood so $ x\neq y$, thus the function is not bijection

Comment: No.  It *is* a bijection.  But your proof is wrong.

Comment: Notice $a|a| \ge 0 \iff a \ge 0$ and $b|b| \ge 0 \iff b \ge 0$ so $a|a| = b|b|$  only if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.  So if you can prove $|a| = |b|$ then in *this* case, since $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, that *would* mean $a = b$.

Comment: You *do* have to know that a.  For every $b \ge 0$ there is a unique $c = \sqrt{b} \ge 0$ so that $c^2 = b$.  That's probably being given to you as a given or maybe that has been proven.  But you will need that.  Equivalently you may have $a^{2n} = b^{2n} \implies |a| = |b|$.  You can use that.  But you can *NOT* use $a^{2n} = b^{2n} \implies a = b$ because that is FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given function is 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{ if } x \geq 0\\
-x^2 & \text{ if } x < 0\\
\end{cases}$$
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $a\geq 0$, then we can choose $x=\sqrt{a}$ to get $f(x)=a$.
If $a< 0$, then we can choose $x=-\sqrt{-a}$ to get $f(x)=a$.

So we can map to any real number. Hence surjective.

**Note:** Also your proof for injectivity needs fixing. This representation of the function can help you with that as well.

Comment: $x\cdot |x| =x^2$?

Comment: @TheGamer the reason for that is $|x|=x$, when $x \geq 0$ and $|x|=-x$, when $x<0$.

Comment: |x| = x if x >= 0 so x|x| = x^2 if x >= 0.  |x| = -x is x < 0 so x|x| = -x^2 if x < 0$..

Comment: @AnuragA is this right for injective: Case1: x,y>0 $$\implies x^2=y^2$$         $$x=y$$  Case1: x,y<0 $$\implies -x^2=-y^2$$         $$x=y$$

Comment: @TheGamer actually you should start with $f(x)=f(y)$, this means both $f-$values have the same sign, so based on the piecewise function I have defined you know that either $f(x)=f(y) \implies x^2=y^2$ (i.e both $x,y \geq 0$) or it $\implies -x^2=-y^2$ (both $x,y <0$) In either case you have $x^2=y^2 \implies x =\pm y$ but based on the domain of the function we know that either both inputs $x,y \geq 0$ or both $x,y <0$. Thus the only possibility is $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for each real $x $,

$$f (-x)=-f (x) $$
$f $ is an odd function $(f (0)=0) $.

For $x>0 , \; f (x)=x^2 \;\;,f'(x)=2x. $

$f $ is continuous at $(0,+\infty) $ and strictly increasing.
thus $f $ is a bijection from $(0,+\infty) $ to  $(\lim_{0^+}x^2=0,\lim_{+\infty}x^2=+\infty) $ 
hence $f $ is a bijection from $\Bbb R $ to $\Bbb R $.

Comment: @DougM $f $ odd implies $f (0)=0$.

Comment: @DougM Thanks. I did it with limits.

Answer (score 0):

If $y\ge 0$ then $y=f(\sqrt y)$. If $y<0$ then $y=f(-\sqrt{-y})$.

Answer (score 0):

$a^4 = b^4 \not \implies a = b$ as $x^4 = k>0$ will have two real solutions $\sqrt[4]{k}$ and $-\sqrt[4]{k}$ so it will be possible that $a = -b \ne b$ yet $a^4 = (-b)^4 = b^4$.

So that's no good.

Indeed the *ONLY* reason one should square both sides to solve an equation is to allow for *opposite* signs of values to become equivalent and to be ignored.  Squaring both sides *ADDS* extra, not necessarily correct "solutions".

$x = 5$ has one solution.

$x^2 = 5^2$ has two solutions.

$x = 5$ *OR* $x = -5$.  $x = -5$ is an added extraneous solution.  Watch out for those.

.....

Anyway....

Surjection is the easy part.

Let $w \in \mathbb R$

Let $sign(w) = -1$ if $w < 0$ and $sign(x) = 1$ if $w \ge 0$.

Let $x = sign(w)*\sqrt{|w|}$.

The $|x| = \sqrt{|w|}$ and $x*|x| = (sign(w))*\sqrt{|w|}*\sqrt{|w|} = sign(w)*\sqrt{|w|^2} = sign(w)*|w| = w$.

Now go back and fix your proof that it is injective.

Comment: fleablood whats sign?

Comment: I just defined it.  sign(w) = -1 if w < 0.  And sign(w)= 1 if w>=0.  It's a function I *just* invented.  Basically if $w$ is a negative number than $sign(w) = -1$.  and if $w$ is not negative then $sign(w) = 1$.  I figured that would be useful.  So I defined it and used it.  Point being $w = sign(w) *|w|$.

Comment: In other words.  If $w \ge 0$ let $x = \sqrt{w}$.  If $w < 0$ let $x = -\sqrt{|w|}=\sqrt{-w}$.  then if $w \ge 0$, $x*|x| = \sqrt{w}*\sqrt{w} = w$.  If $w < 0$ then $x*|x| = -\sqrt{|w|}*|\sqrt{|w|} = -|w| = w$.